# How to rotate a squashed circle (ellipse) in degrees

Tags: javascript, geometry, rotation, ellipse

I draw a circle path with a point (that's circle_x and circle_Y) in my code like this:

```
var circSize    = 15;
var circArc     = 2 * Math.PI; 
var aspectAdd   = 10; 
var circle_x    = (circSize + aspectAdd) * Math.cos(circArc);
var circle_y    = (circSize * Math.sin(circArc);
```

The circle is then squashed with aspectAdd to make it an ellipse.
The ellipse is pure an invisible path that is used as an animation path for another point.
How do I rotate the ellipse in degrees?
It has to be in pure mathematics. I don't use the canvas ctx or svg path script for this instance (where I could easily give a rotation value).

Comment: what you mean rotate? you just have some vars here that you are using to create `circle_x`and `circle_y` that i suppose is just the "center" of the circle, and if you rotate it, the circle is still there, so there is nothing to rotate here (if it's not like this, please explain that are `circle_x` and `circle_y`)

Comment: As I state: it is a circle that i squash so it becomes an ellipse. Then i want to rotate it a given amount of degrees. The var Circle_x and circle_y ar added to a point so it draws an ellipse.

Comment: Maybe it helps when I explain that the aspectAdd is a slider that gives a number to add or subtract width to the circle so it becomes more ore less a ellipse. Also the rotation amount will be a slider that gives a number for rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Equation to find points of ellipse with semi-axes `rx` and `ry`, rotated by angle `fi`.

Calculate points for `t` parameter in range `0..2*Pi` with needed step.

```
x = rx * Cos(t) * Cos(fi) - ry * Sin(t) * Sin(fi) + cx
y = rx * Cos(t) * Sin(fi) + ry * Sin(t) * Cos(fi) + cy
```

Example for for rx=100, ry=60, fi=-Pi/6:

[image]

Addition:
seems you calculate ellipse points in fluid.js file here:

```
var r_x = circle_x * Math.cos(circRot) - circle_y * Math.sin(circRot);
var r_y = circle_x * Math.sin(circRot) + circle_y * Math.cos(circRot);
```

So you need to modify these lines to test them:

```
 var ellipseRot =  Math.PI / 4
    var r_x = circle_x * Math.cos(circRot) * Math.cos(ellipseRot)- circle_y * Math.sin(circRot) * Math.sin(ellipseRot);
    var r_y = circle_x * Math.sin(circRot) *Math.sin(ellipseRot) + circle_y * Math.cos(circRot) * Math.cos(ellipseRot);
```

then change `ellipseRot` with slider

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm very new to JavaScript and mathematics. Perhaps you can show me how to implement the solution in my code above?

Comment: Very nice animation. I added how (I think) to modify fluid.js  - perhaps coordinates are calculated somewhere else.

Comment: Hi MBo, thanks for the compliment. That's appreciated. I don't understand what you propose. The circle rotation is the ellipse rotation. The slider for circRot is the slider for rotating the ellipse. I pasted the code in fluid.js, line 1001 / 1003.  I notice that the aspect ratio throws a spanner in the works. I'm afraid that I address this problem wrong. To circumference the aspect ratio issue I thought that it would be better to draw an invisible SVG or CTX ellipse shape on the dot and let the dot follow the the border of the shape. But  I got completely lost on to find how that's done.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should've asked this in a math stackoverflow.

You need to apply a [rotation to your parameteric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Specifically,

```
r_x = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta)
r_y = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta)
```

I'll let you handle the substitions.

Comment: I was not aware that there is a math stackoverflow. As I'm fearly new to javascript so the implementation of the suggested solutions is very complex for me. Maybe someone can implement the suggestion in my code?

Comment: Just replace x with circle_x, and y with circle_y.

Comment: I did. But because there's is an aspect ration thing happening, I'm lost in solution. You can check my project at https://www.ludotimp.nl/fluid/index.html. best viewed in Chrome. Hover in top left corner to expose menubar.